# themselves (singular or plural)?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, countability

This is the sentence I came across, it's from a game.

> While Dwarven cannon were being loaded, others armed **themselves** with Elven **steel** and **mail**.

To my understanding, *themselves* is a plural word, so *steel* and *mail* should also be in plural form, why they use singular instead???

EDIT: I looked up the word steel as the meaning of sword and it said the word is countable.
[image]

Here is the [link](http://www.dictionaryfocus.com/?action=definition&word=steel).

Comment: In your sentence, **steel** and **mail** are uncountable nouns. Compare it with this: *I will buy you apples, juice and water.*

Comment: @Michael Rybkin See my edit pls.

Comment: Personally, I'd worry more about the sentence itself, the structure of which makes it problematic. I'd be more inclined to write *while some loaded Dwarven cannon, others armed themselves with Elven steel and mail* in order to maintain proper parallelism. Alternatively, *while Dwarven cannon were being loaded, Elven steel and mail was being used as armament*. As it is, the sentence is incorrectly pieced together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the sentence "steel" and "mail" are being used as uncountable nouns.

You note that "a steel" is also (rarely) used as a countable noun, nevertheless, in this sentence it is being used as uncountable. In this context "steel" means *weaponry*, and *weaponry* is usually uncountable.

"Mail" is a type of armour, made of interlocking loops of metal. It is also usually uncountable.